# PyQt5 QFileDialog is not returning correct paths in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pycharm, pyqt5

I'm using this bit of code to open a file dialog and return the selected file names (PyQt5, Ubuntu)

```py
QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, 'Open files', self.__target, self.__open_f)
```

But instead of getting this list:

```py
['/home/python/Downloads/addresses.csv', '/home/python/Downloads/airtravel.csv']
```

I am getting this list:

```py
['/run/user/1000/doc/9f194012/addresses.csv', '/run/user/1000/doc/885466d0/airtravel.csv']
```

here is my code:

```py
import os
import sys
from mods import fixqt
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

from mods.csvdata import DataCSV
from mods.err_report import report_error
from mods.save_xl import save_excel_file
from ui.mainwindow import Ui_mwWCS

# this is the value of self.__target
home = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")
icon_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "ui"), "Icon.ico")
open_filter = "CSV files (*.csv)"
save_filter = "Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)"
input_data = DataCSV([])

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):  # window = qtw.QMainWindow()
    def __init__(self, title="", mw_home="", op_filter="All files (*.*)", sv_filter="All files (*.*)", parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.__title = title 
        self.ui = Ui_mwWCS() 
        self.ui.setupUi(self)  
        self.__target = mw_home
        self.__open_f = op_filter
        self.__save_f = sv_filter
        self.__excel_file = ""
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(icon_path))
        self.__input_data = DataCSV([])

    def __show_dialog(self):
        return QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, 'Open files', self.__target, self.__open_f)

    def __set_csv(self, lst):
        self.__input_data.set_files_list(lst)
        # print(lst)
        self.__input_data.open_csv_files()
        self.__input_data.exception_entries()
        self.__input_data.set_boxes_number()
        self.__input_data.set_plates_number()

    def on_add_clicked(self):
        try:
            list_names, _ = self.__show_dialog()

            self.ui.lstInput.addItems(list_names)
            self.__set_csv(list_names)

        except Exception as e:
            report_error("Error occurred (ADD)", e)
```

Can you please help on how can I get the proper filenames?

**Update:**
trying my code in a terminal worked fine, could it be a problem related to pyCharm?

[image: screenshot from python terminal]

Comment: You will have to post your code for others to help you. Without that no one can know what is going wrong.

Comment: I've only used Ubuntu a few times, but I'm thinking that what's happening here is that Qt is using the "native" file dialog, whose contents are provided by Ubuntu (as in Unity/Gtk), which probably creates a "virtual" folder for the downloads, and which are actually stored in in `/run/user/<userid>/doc/` **or** uses the `~/Downloads` path as a virtual folder, which links to the actual files via symlinking. If that's the case, what's strange here is that, by default, QFileDialog should follow symlinks.

Comment: I'd suggest you to try to do create a normal QFileDialog (no static function) setting the `DontUseNativeDialog` flag to True, to see the file paths; also it might be a good idea to do an `ls -l` on both file paths for the same files (those in `/run` and their counterparts in `~/Downloads`), to see if they are actual files or symbolic links; note that they might even be hard links (but I doubt that), in that case the number following the permission indicates the reference count, and you can check the inode number with `ls -i` to see if it's a match. That said, it could also be a fuse "hack"...

Answer (score 4):

@musicamante, thank you for your help. The answer lays with **DontUseNativeDialog** if I'm running my code with PyCharm. Running it outside PyCharm, that flag isn't required.

Answer (score 3):

I am using PyCharm and I had the same problem. The option "DontUseNativeDialog" as suggested by @musicamante also solved the problem for me.

```
QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent=self, options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue happening for me aswell, finally i figured out the curprit is pycharm (in my case),
try run your code in terminal and you will see it works fine. and after snap package your application it will also run smooth. So this was not a problem for me now.