# PyQt6 QFileDialog.getSaveFileName unsusual response

Tags: python, qfiledialog, pyqt6

I am upgrading a project from PyQt5 to PyQt6. I have getting a strange response when obtaining a filepath to save a file, using PyQt6.

I have checked the directory value: /home/cc/Desktop.

I enter 'test' into the dialog.

```
path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Enter name", directory)
```

The path tuple returns:
('/run/user/1000/doc/3871d7e4/test', '')
but should return
('/home/cc/Desktop/test', '')

Any advice ?

Comment: Are you running your app on a remote machine?

Comment: Maybe you're using PyCharm on Ubuntu? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646908/pyqt5-qfiledialog-is-not-returning-correct-paths-in-ubuntu

Comment: Yes I am using PyCharm on Ubuntu 20.04. And Yes that is the issue. Running in terminal now is fine.